# Getting missing icon error when trying to upload my react native app to apple store but I have all the icons?

Tags: react-native, app-store-connect

I have a react native app I'm getting the following error up I try to publish to the apple app store "Error 1: ​ITMS-90096​ - Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5"

But I have all my icons attached screenshots, I'm on Xcode9 anyone have any ideas

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be a long shot (because of the error message you receive), but I ran into similar issue and this was the solution:

1. Navigate to `Images.xcassets`
2. Look at right sidebar, **Target Membership**
3. Enable checkbox next to your project name.

Comment: It's freezing, so i couldn't click checkbox. But myproject-test is clickable.